# Question about the notation $\binom{n}{k_1,\ k_2,\ldots, \ k_m}$

Tags: notation

I was reading about multinomial expansion on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem). It says,

> $$(x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_m)^n=\sum_{k_1+k_2+\ldots+k_m=n}\binom{n}{k_1,\
>  k_2,\ldots, \ k_m}\prod_{t=1}^mx_t^{k_t}$$ Where $$\binom{n}{k_1,\
>  k_2,\ldots, \ k_m}=\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!\ldots k_m!}$$

I wonder, is$\large\dbinom{n}{k_1,\ k_2,\ldots, \ k_m}$ a well known notation in mathematics and is equal to $\dfrac{n!}{k_1!k_2!\ldots k_m!}$ in other contexts or we defined it only for this specific calculation?

Comment: I think this is a standard notation, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_to_multinomials).

Comment: @azif00 It makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: It is standard with the provision $\sum\limits_{j=1}^m k_j=n$.